# Al intentar desinstalar openJDK 11 en linux mint, aparece "pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generó cortes, esto puede deberse a paquetes retenidos."

Tags: java, linux

Estoy queriendo desinstalar el openJDK 11.0.17 de mi SO Linux Mint y no me deja; intenté varios métodos, pero aún así sigue allí. ¿Hay alguna forma de sacarlo, para después instalar el JDK de Oracle?

Error que me lanza la terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-11-jre
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 default-jre : Depende: openjdk-11-jre pero no va a instalarse
 openjdk-11-jdk : Depende: openjdk-11-jre (= 11.0.17+8-1ubuntu2~18.04) pero no va a instalarse
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generó cortes, esto puede deberse a paquetes retenidos.
```

Intenté con el comando:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-11-jre.
```

No pasó nada y me tira el error de arriba.

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo resolví: para desinstalar el OpenJDK que viene predeterminado en el sistema utilicé nomás el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk*
```

Utilicé ese único comando para desinstalar el JDK que ya viene de fábrica. Linux Mint de 32 bits.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.